# Удаление старых данных по datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

Просьба подсказать простой TSQL запрос для MSSQL
есть данные типа:

> ```
> logins   cards   data
>
> login1   00555   2019-12-12 13:13:13.000
> login1   00666   2020-12-12 13:13:13.000
> login2   11111   2019-12-12 13:13:13.000
> login3   33333   2018-12-12 13:13:13.000
> login3   33333   2019-12-12 13:13:13.000
> login3   33333   2020-12-12 13:13:13.000
> ```

нужно в этой БД найти и отсортировать дубли логинов, 
к примеру login3 повторяется в бд, нужно удалить строки которые старее самой последней даты

удалить:

> login3   33333   2018-12-12 13:13:13.000
>
> login3   33333   2019-12-12 13:13:13.000

оставить:
login3   33333   2020-12-12 13:13:13.000
и так по всем логинам в бд

Comment: пронумеруйте строки в группах по убыванию даты и удалите с номером большим 1

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+row_number+delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE
FROM sourcetable
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM sourcetable t
               WHERE t.logins = sourcetable.logins
                 AND t.data > sourcetable.data );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=8a9377140ed41ae6a569964bce51d4cc)

Желательно наличие индекса `(logins, data)`.

Comment: шикарно, а не подскажите, когда остались незначительные косяки...
одни и те же карты на разные фио, логины, что выдает выборка

SELECT cards, COUNT ()
  FROM DB.Cards
  GROUP BY Cards
  HAVING  COUNT () > 1

как запихнуть это в DELETE чтобы снести все эти записи ?

Comment: @Be1m0nt Это совсем другая задача. Создайте новый вопрос, где дайте ссылку на fiddle с данными, в которых есть все возможные типы косяков, и требуемый результат. С этим работать гораздо проще, чем со словесными объяснениями и таблицами данных аки текст.

Answer (score 1):

Создаем тестовый набор:

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTABLE (logins NVARCHAR(100), cards NVARCHAR(5), [data] datetime);
INSERT #MyTABLE
VALUES ('login1','00555','2019-12-12 13:13:13.000'),('login1','00666','2020-12-12 13:13:13.000'),
('login2','11111','2018-12-12 13:13:13.000'),('login3','33333','2018-12-12 13:13:13.000'),
('login3','33333','2019-12-12 13:13:13.000'),('login3','33333','2020-12-12 13:13:13.000');
```

Пишем CTE, нумеруем строки:

```
WITH del_duplicate AS
(
SELECT 
logins,
cards,
data,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY logins,cards ORDER BY [data] DESC) AS rn 
FROM #MyTABLE
)
```

Удаляем лишнее:

```
DELETE FROM del_duplicate WHERE RN > 1
```

Проверяем результат:

```
SELECT * FROM #MyTABLE
```

Удаляем временную таблицу:

```
DROP TABLE #MyTABLE
```

Подробнее о [OVER Clause](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)